# Label Shape mismatch in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, label, reshape

I am beginner at tensorflow. i want to build a simple model but i got this error.
i think it's because labels but i don't know how to fix it.
i bulid my dataset from directory files with tf.data.Dataset.

this is data set:

visit : https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2EQT.jpg

data

- --------class1: [x.jpeg ...]
- --------class2: [y.png ....]
- .
- .
- .
- --------class10: [z.jpg ...]

```
    data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('D:/Downloads/Image data set/'), 'raw-img')
    data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
    image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.*')))

    list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir / '*/*'), shuffle=False)
    list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

    train_size = int(image_count * 0.8)
    test_size = int(image_count * 0.1)
    val_size = int(image_count * 0.1)
    
    train_ds = list_ds.take(train_size)
    val_ds = list_ds.skip(train_size)
    test_ds = val_ds.skip(test_size)
    val_ds = val_ds.take(test_size)

    def parse_image(filename):
      parts = tf.strings.split(filename, os.sep)
      label = tf.cast(parts[-2] == class_names, tf.float32)
      label = tf.argmax(label)
    
      image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
      image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
      image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
      image = tf.reshape(image, [32, 150, 150, 3])
      return image, labels
    
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    
    train_ds = train_ds.map(parse_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = val_ds.map(parse_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    test_ds = test_ds.map(parse_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        kr.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150 ,3)),
        kr.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        kr.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
        kr.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        kr.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
        kr.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        kr.layers.Flatten(),
        kr.layers.Dense(128, activation='softmax'),
        kr.layers.Dense(10)
    ])
    
    model.compile(
      optimizer='adam',
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(
      train_ds,
      epochs=3
    )
```

error :
this is error when i want to fit the model.

```
Train for 20943 steps
Epoch 1/3
    1/20943 [..............................] - ETA: 1:14:41
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-c408313d0649> in <module>
      1 model.fit(
      2   train_ds,
----> 3   epochs=3
      4 )

    
.
.
.
.

ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (320,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (32, 10)).
```

Comment: Please include what kind of filenames you make your labels from (how they look like and how you want to make them look like as labels), so that we can check where it goes wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved by using batch size and step_per_epoch variables.

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(parse_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.cache()
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

and train

```
history = model.fit(train_ds, steps_per_epoch = train_size // BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs = EPOCHS, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
        validation_data = val_ds, validation_steps = val_size // BATCH_SIZE)
```

and SOLVED.